# UK Gift Aid tax percentage

Tags: gift-aid-extension

We are running civicrm 5.30.0 and UK Gift Aid 3.4.6. Our tax calculation is set to 25% and yet imported contributions or those added on-line all calculate at 33.33%?

I cannot find anywhere else that this figure is set

Answer (score 1):

I was advised by another organisation to set the tax rate to 20% and this is now working correctly showing the correct gift aid amount as calculated at 25%. So this matter is now sorted.

Comment: Yes. Should have spotted this earlier. 20% is the correct value for UK Gift Aid being the current basic tax rate. The confusion is that this is the tax rate on the amount you effectively donated before tax whereas the amount you actually donate is after tax. So with a tax rate of 20% you get gift aid of 25% of the amount you actually donate. For example, if someone donates £80 then you get 25% of that in gift aid (£20). So effectively the person has donated £100 which they will have paid 20% in tax (£20) which you claim back as gift aid.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the options to set the tax rate by navigating to Administer >> CiviContributue>> Giftaid>> Giftaid tax rate.

If you have already imported contribution with different rate then you would have to run a data fix from mysql.

Alternatively, Create a profile ONLY with Contribution >>> Eligible for giftaid field

Then, go to Find contribution, search any with wrong amount and select "Update multiple contribution" from action menu. Execute the process and see  if that helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but it has been set to 25% as I said in the question and was set using the menu options that you stated

Comment: @DaveHassall Hi I have updated my answer. Please try that.